# The Movement is weird

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following Welton King's tutorial on how to make an fps, I am on the 3rd video and I have written this.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Com.Pat12.FPS
{
    public class Motion : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed;
        public float sprintModifier;
        public float jumpForce;
        public Camera normalCam;
        public Transform groundDetector;
        public LayerMask ground;
        private Rigidbody rig;
        private float baseFOV;
        private float sprintFOVModifier = 1.5f;
     
        private void Start()
        {
            baseFOV = normalCam.fieldOfView;
            Camera.main.enabled = false;
            rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }

        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            //Axis
            float t_hmove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float t_vmove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            //Controls
            bool sprint = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift);
            bool jump = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);
            //States
            bool isGrounded = Physics.Raycast(groundDetector.position, Vector3.down, 0.1f, ground);
            bool isJumping = jump && isGrounded;
            bool isSprinting = sprint && t_vmove > 0 && !isJumping && isGrounded;
            //Jumping
            if (isJumping)
            {
                rig.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
            }
            //Movement
            Vector3 t_direction = new Vector3(t_hmove, 0, t_vmove);
            t_direction.Normalize();
            float t_adjustedSpeed = speed;
            if (isSprinting) t_adjustedSpeed *= sprintModifier;
            Vector3 t_targetVelocity = t_direction * t_adjustedSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            t_targetVelocity.y = rig.velocity.y;
            rig.velocity = t_targetVelocity;
            //FOV
            if (isSprinting) 
            { 
                normalCam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(normalCam.fieldOfView, baseFOV * sprintFOVModifier, Time.deltaTime * 8f); 
            }
            else 
            { 
                normalCam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(normalCam.fieldOfView, baseFOV, Time.deltaTime * 8f); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the w key is not going forward when I turn my player. It is only moving according to the ground irrespective of the face.

Comment: @PalleDue `float t_vmove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");` is the `w` key, and any value over `0` indicates the key has been pressed.

Comment: `The Movement is weird` is not a valid problem description .. please come up with a better title

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. You had to make it `transform.TransformDirection(t_direction )`

Comment: Note that this takes eventual scaling into account! If you want it unscaled you might want to rather use `rig.rotation * t_direction` which in general I would recommend when using physics and not use anything from transform at all